# What does the sum of two qubits tell about their correlations?

Tags: research-level, quantum-information, correlation-functions, density-operator

> How much can I learn about correlations between two quits by measuring
>   the sum of their values? What is the best way to formalize such a
>   question?

Below is my original, longer formulation of the same question in spin language.
I have an ensemble of pairs of spin-$1/2$ particles. All I can do is to measure total $S_z$ for each pair, each time learning  one of the three standard outcomes: $+1$, $0$ or $-1$. Based on the knowledge of this probability distribution $P(S_z)$, what can be said about the density matrix of my ensemble? In particular, what is best measure for correlations between the two particles in these circumstances?

I understand that I won't be able to distinguish whether the correlations are classical or necessarily quantum-mechanical, but struggle to come up with a measure better than a classical correlation coefficient $$r=\frac{\langle s_1 s_2 \rangle-\langle s_1 \rangle \langle s_2 \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle (s_1- \langle s_1 \rangle)^2 \rangle \langle (s_2- \langle s_2 \rangle)^2 \rangle }}$$  where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the $\pm 1/2$ spin projections (or $0$, $1$ qubit values) of the 1st and the 2nd particle, respectively, so that my only observable can be expressed as $S_z=s_1+s_2$. I then minimize $r$ over all possible   $\langle s_1 \rangle$ and $\langle s_1 \rangle$ consistent with measured $P(S_z)$ and declare that the outcome is the minimal possible correlation in the pair. Is there a more elegant way?

**UPDATE:**
Classically, if we take the definition of zero correlations as $\langle s_1 s_2 \rangle =\langle s_1  \rangle \langle s_2 \rangle$, then it implies that $s_1 = +1/2$ and $s_2=+1/2$ with some *independent* probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$, so that the sum is distributed bimomially $P(+1)=p_1 p_2$ and $P(-1)=(1-p_1)(1-p_2)$. These two equations have a solution with $0\leq p_1, p_2 \leq 1$ only if $$P(+1) < 1-2 \sqrt{P(-1)}+P(-1)$$

Graphically, this condition is satisfied within the region bounded by a black line in the plot below. The rest of the available probability space is the region of excess correlations ($r_{\text{min}}>0$, depicted in red). 
[image]

**Updated question:** is there a quantum loophole in such analysis? I suspect not but would really like to come up with a shorter/cleaner argument.

**Update no. 2** My selected spin/qubit degree of freedom is one of the many variables characterizing the state of the two particles. Can we be sure there exists no pure product state that can lead to $r_{\text{min}}>0$? See a [related active question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62178/) on fermionic entanglement of two particles.

**Update no. 3** The work that motivated this question has been published in [Nature Nanotechnology](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nnano.2014.275); the open access version is [arXiv:1404.0030](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0030).

Comment: Will the special case of a pure (but otherwise arbitrarily entangled) composite system be of interest to you.

Comment: A pure superposition of 00 and 11 will cover the maximal correlation diagonal in the plot, so I wont be surprized if a pure stat can land anywhere in then triangle. Would be nice to  see a measure of minimal entanglement required to reach a particular point.

Comment: The idea is to use the classification given in http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0006068 (Geometry of entangled states) by Marek Kuś Karol Žyczkowski. The manifolds of equal entanglement of the pure two-qubit system fall into three strata parameterized by a single parameter $\theta$. The nongeneric orbits are $\mathbb{R}P^3$ and $S^2 \times S^2 $ correspond to $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 $ respectively. The generic orbits correspond to $0 < \theta <\frac{\pi}{2}$ are five dimensional twisted $S^2$ bundles over $\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Comment: Cont. What is important is that on each manifold type there is an explicit parameterization of the 4-dimensional state vector (in terms of 3, 4, and 5 parameters respectively). (The generic case is not written explicitly in the article but can be easily worked out). Given the state vector, the $S_z$ probability distribution can be explicitly computed for each type of orbit and compared to the experimental distribution

Comment: @David, this is great! The manifold of (pure) density matrices for fixed  $\theta$ will in this way be mapped onto a well-defined domain in the space of $P(S_z)$'s. I'm specially interested in the map of $\theta=0$ (separable states = a good quantum analog of uncorrelated variables). Please post an answer, even a sketchy one, to stake a claim to  the bounty.

Comment: Of course, if you allow for mixed states any outcome can be explained from an unentangled (i.e. separable) state.

Comment: @Norbert Exactly. So, delineating cleanly the pure quantum limit will complement and complete the classical correlation analysis.

Comment: @Slaviks Probably one can also ask for trade-offs between mixedness and entanglement. I guess it depends what you want to use this for.

Comment: I'd be very surprized if the zero entanglement domain will be anything different from zero classical correlation domain. But let's see how it works out...

Comment: @Slaviks I agree. But if you only want to characterize the zero correlation domain, then you only have to show that (quantum) product states do not work better, and this follows immediately (even for the mixed case!) from the fact that only the diagonal elements of the  density matrices are ever involved.

Comment: I expect an experimental point (uncertainty ellipse) deep in the correlated region & I want to be able to claim something like "if this is a pure state, then it should be at least ... [number] of [most appropriate entanglement measure] at 95% confidence.

Comment: Do you have good reason to think that your state is pure, or close to pure ? And do you have any way to measure the spin in another direction ?

Comment: Yes, there are good reasons to expect high-fidelity pure state although present set of data does not prove it (because only $S_z$ is measured so there is always an option to justify correlations classically). We'll see how this develops and I'll post a link to the paper once it is out.

Comment: Then, I think I've found the solution (I've updated my answer accordingly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edited to add the second part*

*Edited again, for part 3 and 4*

$\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|#1\right>} \newcommand\bra[1]{\left<#1\right|} $

## 1. Absence of Quantum Loophole

You can easily see that there is no "quantum loophole" in your argument by writing explicitly any pure separable state. With your notations, we have :
$$ 
\left(\sqrt{p_1}\ket\uparrow+e^{i\phi_1}\sqrt{1-p_1}\ket{\downarrow}\right)
\left(\sqrt{p_2}\ket\uparrow+e^{i\phi_2}\sqrt{1-p_2}\ket{\downarrow}\right)
$$
This expression obviously corresponds to all possible separable pure state and gives the uncorrelated distribution you describe.

Of course, as @Norbert Schuch said, if you allow for mixed states, you have access to whole region, which is the same as saying that you allow classical correlations.

To detect quantum correlations, as you are probably aware, you will need to have information about another direction, like $S_x$.

## 2. Lower bound of entanglement of a pure state

If you are *sure* that your state $\ket\psi$ is pure, you can have a lower bound of its entanglement. Let $P_\pm$ and $P_0$ be the three spin probabilities. The state you have can be written 
$$\ket{\psi}=\sqrt{P_+}\ket{\uparrow\uparrow} + e^{i\phi}\sqrt{P_-}\ket{\downarrow\downarrow} +\sqrt{P_0}(\alpha\ket{\uparrow\downarrow}+\beta\ket{\downarrow\uparrow}) \text{ with } |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$$
Since our measurement does not distinguish what happens in the $S_Z=0$ subspace, we probably have no information about the entanglement there. So we can take the fidelity $F$ with a maximally entangled correlated state for entanglement measure. We have
$$
F:=\max_{\theta}\left|\left<\psi\right|\frac{\ket{\uparrow\uparrow}+e^{i\theta}\ket{\downarrow\downarrow}}{\sqrt2}\right|^2=\frac{\left(\sqrt{P_+}+\sqrt{P_-}\right)^2}2
$$
You cannot prove entanglement when $F=\tfrac12$. This corresponds to the zero correlation line :-)

Of course, all this is only valid for pure states, and could also correspond to classically correlated states.

## 3. Lower bound, take 2

Since the state is pure, its entanglement is fully characterized by the eigenvalues $\lambda_\pm$
 of its partial trace $\rho=Tr_B \ket\psi \bra\psi$. They are the solutions of 
$\lambda^2-\lambda+\det\rho$ and are given by
$\lambda_\pm=\tfrac12 \pm \sqrt{\tfrac14 -\det\rho}.$
We have the Schmidt decomposition
$\ket{\psi}=\sqrt{\lambda_+}\ket{0}\otimes\ket{0}+\sqrt{\lambda_-}\ket{1}\otimes\ket{1}$,
where the $\ket{i}$s are the bases which diagonalise $ Tr_B \ket\psi \bra\psi$ and 
$ Tr_A \ket\psi \bra\psi$.

Before computing $\det\rho$, one can see that $0\le\det\rho\le\tfrac14$. When $\det\rho=0$, $\lambda_+= 1$, $\lambda_-=0$ and
$\ket\psi$ is separable ; when $\det\rho=\tfrac14$, 
$\lambda_+=\lambda_-=\tfrac12$ and
$\ket\psi$ is maximally entangled. 
The bigger $\det\rho$ is, the more $\ket\psi$ is entangled.
More quantitatively, the entropy of entanglement of this state is $h(\lambda_-)$ where $h(\cdot)$ is the binary entropy function and the negativity of the state is $\det\rho$.

\begin{align}
\det\rho
  &=\left(P_++P_0|\alpha|^2\right)\left(P_-+P_0|\beta|^2\right)
  -\left| \beta\sqrt{P_0P_+}+\alpha^*e^{i\phi}\sqrt{P_0P_-}\right|^2
  \\
 &=P_+P_- +|P_0\alpha\beta|^2 +P_0\left(
   |\alpha|^2P_-+ |\beta|^2P_+
   - |\beta|^2P_ +- |\alpha|^2P_-
  - 2 Re\left( \beta \alpha^*e^{i\phi}\sqrt{P_+P_-}
  \right)\right)\\
  &=\left| \sqrt{P_+P_-}   + \beta \alpha^*e^{i\phi} P_0 \right|^2
\end{align}
We want a lower bound on the entanglement. We therefore chose the free parameters
$\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\phi$ in order to minimize $\det\rho$. Since we have 
$|\alpha\beta|\le\tfrac12$, $\min\det\rho=0$ if $ \sqrt{P_+P_-}\le \tfrac12 P_0$. 
This corresponds to the separability limit established earlier.

If we have 
$|\alpha\beta|\le\tfrac12$, then
$$
  \min\det\rho=\left( \sqrt{P_+P_-}- \tfrac12 P_0\right)^2
   =\tfrac14 \left[\left(\sqrt{ P_+}+ \sqrt{ P_-}\right)^2 - 1\right]^2
   = \left(F-\tfrac12\right)^2.
$$
For these minimally entangled states, $\lambda_\pm=\frac12\pm\sqrt{F(1-F)}$.

## 4. Bonus : an upper bound on the entanglement

One can also look at an upper bound on the entanglement with the same approach:
$$
  \max\det\rho= \left| \sqrt{P_+P_-}   + \tfrac12 P_0 \right|^2
    = \left(G-\tfrac12\right)^2 \text{ with } G=\tfrac12\left( \sqrt{ P_+} - \sqrt{ P_-}\right)^2.
$$
For these "maximally" entangled states, $\lambda_\pm=\frac12\pm\sqrt{G(1-G)}$.

A good way to put all this on a graph is to take $\sqrt{P_\pm}$ as coordinates. The possible measurement are in the top right quarter of a disk and the bound described here are constant along 45° straight lines.

Comment: If you have a non-trivial bound on the purity of your state, you can also compute a bound on $ F $.

Comment: I have to admit I don't find the argument why to neglect the Sz=0 subspace very convincing.

Comment: @Norbert This appaerntly relies on good intuitive understanding of fidelity as a measure, which I unfortunatelly do not posses. I see the route proposed by David Bar Moshe as quite solid, still need to work it out though

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: You don't have to buy this argument, since we only need a lower bound. However, one can make this more rigorous by looking into the fidelity with a general maximally entangled state of the form $\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle} I\otimes U(\ket{\uparrow\uparrow}+\ket{\downarrow\downarrow})/\sqrt2$. The latter form is not too complicated and allows to also have an upper bound on the possible entanglement.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Another way to see my argument is to see that the measurement give no information about $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If $\alpha=1,\beta=0$ the state in the $S_Z=0$ subspace is separable ; if $\alpha=\beta=1/\sqrt2$, it is maximally entangled.

Comment: @Slaviks: All entanglement measures are equivalent in the pure 2-qubits states. What kind of measure would you prefer ? By the way, I thought that fidelity was the easiest measure to grasp intuitively. Can you tell me what you get, and what you don't get ? (I know, that last question is by definition very tricky...)

Comment: @Slaviks: Using the expression of $\left|\psi\right>$, one can show that if $F>1/2$, the [Schmidt coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition) of the least entangled pure state are $\sqrt{(1\pm2\sqrt{F(F-1)})/2}$. This allows to easily compute the minimal [Entropy of Entaglement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_entanglement)

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans Thanks a lot for your explanations and links! I'll study and see for a formulation which appeals most for the target community (condensed matter with experimental emphasis).

Comment: One can brute force compute the eigenvalues of the RDM for a general two-qubit state of the above form, and then analytically determine the points with the lowest Schmidt coefficient = entanglement. It is pretty painful, but more or less straightforward.

Comment: @Slaviks Ok, I finished the brute force calculation and I can indeed reproduce Frederic's result above.  If you are interested in can try to write it up. (It's a painful load of steps, although each of them is simple.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You don't really need to brute force all the stuff. One can quite quickly get rid of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\phi$ from simple arguments. And one can also get an upper bound on entanglement from the same arguments.

Comment: @Frederic I agree that there shouldn't be a need to brute force. However, while your argument does make sense to me on an intuitive level, I don't see how to easily convert it into a proof. Vaguely speaking, what one should do is to first maximize the fidelity over all max. entangled states for fixed $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (this gives the entanglement of that state), and then minimize over all $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The way you argue is essentially the other way around: You first get rid of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and then maximize the fidelity. It's still a mistery to me why this works ;-)

Comment: @Norbert : I've added a more detailed and more complete answer, without mystery ;-)

Comment: @Frederic: Thanks, no mystery left!  On the other hand, you *did* compute it brute force (though the determinant indeed provides a pretty elegant way to do so).

Answer (score 3):

Computation of the $S_z$ probability distribution for each of the
manifolds of equal entanglement:

Remark: Notations and references from  [Kuś and Žyczkowski](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0006068) are used.

Case 1: The separable case: The state vector is parametrized as (equation: 24)

$w = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \alpha \cos \beta e^{i \chi_1},& \cos \alpha \sin\beta  e^{i \chi_2}, &\sin \alpha \cos\beta e^{-i \chi_1}, & \sin \alpha \sin \beta e^{-i \chi_1} \end{bmatrix}^{t}$

Here is the computation of the the probability distribution of $S_z$ for
the most general pure two qubit state vector:

The total spin projector operator is given by

$S_z = \frac{1}{2} \sigma_3 \otimes 1_2 +   1_2 \otimes \frac{1}{2}\sigma_3$

The characteristic function of the probability distribution is given by:

$ \Phi_{S_z}(t) = w^{\dagger} e^{i t S_z} w  =P(S_z = 1) e^{it} + P(S_z = 0)+ P(S_z = -1) e^{-it}$

From which the probability distribution can be read:

$P(S_z = 1) =  \cos^2 \alpha\cos^2 \beta $

$P(S_z = 0) = \cos^2 \alpha\sin^2 \beta+ \sin^2 \alpha\cos^2 \beta $

$P(S_z = -1) =  \sin^2 \alpha\sin^2 \beta $

Case 2: The maximally entangled case: The state vector is parameterized as (equation: 23)

$w = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} \cos \alpha  e^{i \chi_1},& \sin \alpha   e^{i \chi_2}, &\sin \alpha  e^{-i \chi_1}, & \cos \alpha  e^{-i \chi_1} \end{bmatrix}^{t}$

In this case:

$P(S_z = 1) =  \frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \alpha$

$P(S_z = 0) =  \sin^2 \alpha$

$P(S_z = -1) =  \frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \alpha $

Case 3: The generic case: The state vector has been worked out:

$w = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2\eta}} \begin{bmatrix} (\cos \alpha \cos \beta -\sin\eta e^{i\phi}\sin\alpha \sin\beta) e^{i \chi_1},& (\cos \alpha \sin\beta + \sin\eta e^{i\phi} \sin\alpha \cos \beta) e^{i \chi_2}, \\&(\sin \alpha \cos\beta + \sin\eta e^{i\phi} \cos\alpha \sin \beta) e^{-i \chi_1}, & (\sin \alpha \sin \beta  -\sin\eta e^{i\phi} \cos\alpha\cos\beta) e^{-i \chi_2} \end{bmatrix}^{t}$

Please, observe that this state vector interpolates between the separable case at $\eta =0$ and the maximally entangled case at $\eta =\frac{\pi}{2}  $ (in this case it depends  on a single combination $\alpha ,  \beta, \phi$  making two of them redundant.

This state vector describes the generic orbit for $0<\eta< \frac{\pi}{2}$.

The angle $\eta$ is related to the angle $\theta$ used in the article by the relation:

$ \sin\theta = \frac{2\sin\eta}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2\eta}}$

In this case, we obtain:

$P(S_z = 1) = \frac{1}{1+\sin^2\eta} ( \cos^2 \alpha\cos^2 \beta + \sin^2 \alpha\sin^2 \beta \sin^2 \eta  - 2\cos\alpha\cos \beta \sin \alpha\sin \beta \sin \eta \cos \phi)$

$P(S_z = 0) = \frac{1}{1+\sin^2\eta} ( \cos^2 \alpha\sin^2 \beta (1+\sin^2\eta)+ \sin^2 \alpha\cos^2 \beta (1+\sin^2\eta)  + 4\cos\alpha\cos \beta \sin \alpha\sin \beta \sin \eta \cos \phi)$

$P(S_z = -1) = \frac{1}{1+\sin^2\eta} (\sin^2 \alpha\sin^2 \beta + \cos^2 \alpha\cos^2 \beta \sin^2 \eta  - 2\cos\alpha\cos \beta \sin \alpha\sin \beta \sin \eta \cos \phi)$

Comment: This is a very useful answer as well, make the decision on the bounty awkwardly difficult. At this stag I'm not yet sure which we will finally use, but the answer by @Frédéric Grosshans is somewhat more diverse and bring in a number of useful contexts. Thanks to both of you for the clear ideas and the effort for write them up properly!